# Draw lines in a 3-d scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, data-science, linear-regression

I have a 3d scatter plot. And I want to draw two lines that will describe dots for 2021 and 2022. Is there any way to do it in matplotlib? I will attach I want it to look like. The black line are the ones I need.

[image]

I tried to ask chat gpt, but it didn't understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it.
Here is a code if someone is interested:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(playlists["Year"], playlists["Playlist title number"] , playlists["Playlist views"], c='r', marker='o')
ax.set_xticks([2021, 2022])

ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Playlist Title Number')
ax.set_zlabel('Views')

playlists_2021=playlists.loc[playlists['Year'] == 2021]
playlists_2022=playlists.loc[playlists['Year'] == 2022]

x = playlists_2021["Playlist title number"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = playlists_2021["Playlist views"]
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

y_pred = reg.predict(x)

ax.plot(np.tile(2021, y_pred.shape), playlists_2021["Playlist title number"], y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=2)

x = playlists_2022["Playlist title number"].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = playlists_2022["Playlist views"]
reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

y_pred = reg.predict(x)

ax.plot(np.tile(2022, y_pred.shape), playlists_2022["Playlist title number"], y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=2)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks like you're better at solving problems than explaining them to an AI... Good job.

Comment: While sharing the code might be helpful, usually a brief explaination of why it answer the question will make the answer better received and very likely will help to make it easier to find it.